# Haskell - counting with foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Working on a Haskell problem, fairly new to the language. I am trying to count the occurence of tuple values that are present in the list of tuples.

My tuples look like this: `[(5, [7,2]), (2,[5,7,1,6])]`

So far, using `foldr`, I have done this:

```
testFunc = foldr (\x-> const succ) 0
```

However, this only retrieves the count of the left side of the tuple. I am a little confused, how to solve this?

-- Expected output: 6

-- Current output: 2

Comment: `testFunc = length . (>>= snd)`

Comment: you are _fairly new_ to Haskell, ***you*** wrote this incredibly dense code `foldr (\x-> const succ) 0`, it ***returns `2`***, and you are a ***little*** confused about it? you haven't even tried running it. (and I am talking to a deleted user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

This means that the function it's talking should take the current value and the accumulator and will return a value of the same type as the accumulator. It then takes an initial value for the accumulator, and finally the `Foldable` thing to iterate over.

The accumulator is clearly the count, and for an empty list, it'll be zero, so there's our initial accumulator value.

We then just have to add the length of the list to that accumulator each time through. We can pattern match this data out. We'll use `_` for the first item in each tuple, because we just don't care about that value.

```
Prelude> testData = [(5, [7,2]), (2,[5,7,1,6])]
Prelude> foldr (\(_, lst) count -> count + length lst) 0 testData
6
Prelude>
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this with only one lambda variable?

Comment: The function you pass to `foldr` or `foldl` takes two arguments. That's just the way it's defined.

Comment: If you don't actually have to use `foldr`, you can use `sum` (which abstracts away the "add up a bunch of number" part of what the lambda expression shown here does. `sum (map (\x -> length (snd x)) testData)` or `sum (map (length . snd) testData)`, or `sum [length v | (_, v) <- testData]`.

Comment: Agreed. I considered adding basically all of those to my answer, but felt it worked better being more focussed.

Comment: My comment is probably better as a comment to the question, but at the same time better presented as an alternative to the correction to `foldr` the OP is asking for. (Plus, it's not helpful if the OP is *required* to use `foldr`.)